# Angular npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, git, bash, angular

All of the sudden I get this error this morning - `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` I'm using windows 10 and Git bash.

This was when trying to simply create a new Angular project via `ng new new-project`. It's happened while doing other random things like installing the CLI tools and installing packages.

Sometimes I can resolve the issue by running Windows CMD as admin, other times that doesn't work. Sometimes if I just keep running the command, eventually it'll work?!!

I've tried a number of steps to resolve including -

- Running CMD as admin
- Powershell as admin
- `npm cache clean`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm cache verify`
- Uninstalling node and re installing
- Changing permission settings on AppData/Roaming/npm
- Deleting files in AppData/Roaming/npm/nodemodules

I've seen quite a few posts about this. Has anyone come across this error lately?

I'm running -

- Angular CLI: 1.5.0
- Node: 8.9.0
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 5.0.0

Thanks

Comment: I've decided to give up on Windows rights error. What I do, that takes time but work, is that when I encounter this error, I launch my command until the error disappears. You should also check if the folder doesn't need admin permissions. Could you at least still post the whole error ?

Answer (score 1):

Click Start.
In the Start Search box, type cmd, and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.
If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click Continue.

cd [*path to project*]

and write your command again.

2 option (Works for me)
install choco and reinstall npm as choco package.